# JavaScript | Angular | Mediator Pattern: Tactics for Obviating Circular Dependencies In AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, mediator, event-driven

### Ways to Implement Dependency Inversion Principle in AngularJS

#### Case Study: The Mediator Pattern

Normally, implementing a Mediator/Director entails both *Director* **and** *Colleague(s)* having a reference to each other. **Not difficult when Director is responsible for *Module-Lifecycle Management (MLM)***:

Director creates Colleagues while passing itself in during construction:

```
var Director = function Director($$) {
    ...

    function init(...) {
        _moduleA = new ModuleA(this);
        _moduleB = new ModuleX(this);
        _moduleX = new ModuleX(this);
    }

    function moduleChanged(ref) {
        if (ref === _moduleXYZ) _moduleC.run(ref.datum);
    }

    return this;
};
```

#### The Tricky Part: Angular

AngularJS automatically *takes on the burden of MLM*, so its tough to use the approach above. We *could* modify our Director.init method slightly:

```
_moduleX = $dependency;
...
_moduleX.init(this);
```

But [my] Colleagues need a reference to Director **at construction-time**.

#### Question and Explanation

While my Director *is* implemented as EDM (Event-Driven Mediation) to run away from needing DIP, I now need Colleagues to reference Director:

```
var Colleague = function Colleague(director) {
    var thus = this;
    ...

    director.publish(director.CHANNELS.SOME_CHANNEL_NAME, data);

    ...
    return this;
};
```

This is because Director *must* now provide Module Authorization (MA):

```
var Director = function Director($$) {
    ...

    function subscribe(channel, handler) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
        $rootScope.$on.apply($rootScope, args);
        return this;
    }

    function publish(channel) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
        if (channel in this.CHANNELS) $rootScope.$broadcast.apply($rootScope, args);
        return this;
    }

    return this;
};
```

**That said, there's virtually NO-DIFFERENCE -- as far as DIP/DI is concerned -- between this approach and the more *Classical*, object-reference driven approach first mentioned**.

So my question is, what are different ways that I can *elegantly* impose DIP and MLM in Angular without running into problems with the framework?

#### Concerns & Potential Workarounds

- `_colleague.init(this);`: BAD
- `_colleague = Colleague.call($dependency, this)`: Healthy for Singletons???
- Split state-driven mediation and apply Director Interface to each Colleague
- Mediator Abstract Class [SEE below]

**Apply Director Interface to each Colleague**

Import (DI) a *Mediator* class into each Colleague:

```
var Mediator = function Mediator($rootScope) {
    ...

    function subscribe(channel, handler) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
        $rootScope.$on.apply($rootScope, args);
        return this;
    }

    function publish(channel) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
        if (channel in this.CHANNELS.SOME_CHANNEL_NAME) $rootScope.$broadcast.apply($rootScope, args);
        return this;
    }

    return this;
};
angular.factory('Mediator', () => Mediator);


var Colleague = function Colleague(Mediator) {
    var thus = this;
    ...

    this.publish(this.CHANNELS.SOME_CHANNEL_NAME, data);

    // export precepts
    Mediator.apply(this);
    this.init = init;
    ...

    return this;
};
```

But this *could* deprive Director of opportunities to mediate based upon high-level application-state, since it won't be a Singleton. E.G:

```
if (this.state.patientInfoStepComplete) _module.run(ref.datum);
```

**Abstract Mediator Class**

As in GoF, the *Participants* include a **Mediator** and a **ConcreteMediator**.

---

- **Mediator**:

  - *Defines an Interface for communication with Colleague objects*
- **ConcreteMediator**:

  - *Implements cooperative behavior by coordinating Colleague objects*
  - *knows and maintains its colleagues*

---

To follow a little closer to DIP, can we take "`this.CHANNELS`" and encapsulate it in *Mediator*, but *ConcreteMediator* would still need a reference to it and Colleague would need a reference to whatever is providing **both** `.CHANNELS` and `.publish(...)`.

You may wonder why I need a "Concrete Mediator" when I'm already implementing something of an "Abstract Mediator" through the use of `.CHANNELS` which can provide *Request-Routing* anyway since its keys are used by Colleagues to abstract a *Channel-Name* value. The reason is that, while `.CHANNELS` *can* route one request to another, it can only do that -- *one single request* -- while `.publish(...)` can provide *one-to-many* handling **AND** work as middleware in other ways as well (e.g: MA).

```
var _actions = {
    'SOME_CHANNEL_NAME': (e, a, b, c) => {
        $rootScope.emit('a', a);
        $rootScope.emit('b', b);
        $rootScope.emitemit('c', c);
    },
};

function publish() {
    ...
    if (channel in this.CHANNELS) _actions[channel].apply(_actions, args);
    ...
}
```

Any ideas or patterns you've used or can think of?

Any cool, non-standard tricks for registering/accessing dependencies in Angular?

Any way in Angular to configure another dependency to be injected to Services at run-time?

Call `angular.constant('contreteMediator', this);` at run-time inside of Director?

Middleware for the Provider-Construction process?

`#PreThanks`

Comment: In my opinion, I don't think that the Mediator pattern really works for JavaScript. The reason Mediator Pattern works in C# is the powerful interface system, which you can't do in JavaScript due to the lack of static typings. You may find something like the Strategy Pattern working slightly better for the CQRS pattern

Comment: I would agree with in almost entirety. CQRS? Sounds like some stuff I always think [hard] about when I'm implementing Even-Driven Architectures in JS. Thx for the reference!
http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html

Comment: I'm writing an example CQRS pattern in Angular at the moment to give you an idea... whether it will work or not... in principle its easy.... in practice, welll...

Comment: The beauty of JavaScript is that is is easier to handle the passing of objects around because you don't have to worry about the static typing!! so if you compare to MediatR (Jimmy Bogard) you don't have to specify your return objects, which means you don't really have to think about it (good/bad you can debate)

Comment: After much thought, the fact that JS is a dynamically typed language, you actually remove the point for putting a pattern in place to execute these Requests because you don't actually need a way to get past the restrictions on the return typings. You may as well stick with the pattern of using a factory for the http request logic and view logic...

Comment: @CallumLinington, thx for the explanation(s) -- please do post a comment with a fiddle or something with an example of that Angular CQRS pattern!

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on "You may as well stick with the pattern of using a factory for the http..."? Was this related to CQRS or DIP/Mediation/Angular from the question? -- thx